# Send a message to the command line when there is no second argument Python

Tags: python, windows, command-line, python-3.4

I just started experimenting with running a program on the command line

I'm working with a script that takes a csv file and uploads it to a mysql database, I'm putting a csv file as an argument so `Script.py filelocation`, when run it works well the only thing I'd like to do now is have a function I can call where if a second argument isn't placed it doesn't crash id like to have a message displayed to the command line like `something went wrong please try again` or something of that kind instead of just crashing.

I haven't worked on command line at all and I'm really struggling

**EDIT**

I apologize for not including my code earlier.

```
def param_check():

# Checks the number of parameters.
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    print("Parameters are correct.")

elif len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Parameter missing... Please input CSV file.")
    exit(1)

else:
    print("Too many parameters... Please try again.")
    exit(1)
```

It keeps assuming that the parameters are always more than 2 so the output is always

```
Too many parameters... Please try again.
```

Comment: Use Exception Handling

Comment: could you show code to elaborate what you mean exactly?

Comment: Try Python's "argparse" module. It helps you parsing command line and outputs a message if an option is missing.

Comment: The first (zeroeth) argument is the script name itself. If you have two parameters, `sys.argv` will have length 3.

Answer (score 0):

Example for Exception Handling

```
import sys
try:
  print ('Argument List:', str(sys.argv[1]))
except:
  print('something went wrong please try again')
  sys.exit()
```

**Goto below link to Know More:**

> https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
print(len(sys.argv))
print(str(sys.argv))
if ( len(sys.argv)<2 ) :
    print("need argument...")
    sys.exit()
print("parameter :", sys.argv[1])


C:\Users\crazy>python a.py a b c
4
['a.py', 'a', 'b', 'c']
parameter : a

C:\Users\crazy>python a.py a
2
['a.py', 'a']
parameter : a

C:\Users\crazy>python a.py
1
['a.py']
need argument...
```